# Updating a section of a webpage with using new data from node.js backend

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to make an app that grabs a song a user is listening to using a scraper. Right now I can get the user to visit the page and see the song title that is being listened to, but if the song updates they will need to refresh the entire page on their own. I am looking for a way to run the code I have in the routes file and then render the page with the song data, then check every now and then if the data has changed and then refresh the section of the page with the new data.

Here's what I want to happen:

1. User sends GET to /songinfo.
2. app.get scrapes the data from an outside source.
3. app.get renders the ejs file with song data
4. Timer goes off/user presses manual refresh button on the page itself
5. New data is rendered onto the page and he rest of the website doesn't refresh. Only the song data is refreshed.

Thanks.

Comment: did you give my answer a try? did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

You can create a new route on your nodejs server that returns song data as [json](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) rather than rendering an EJS file to the client.

Imagine your code is currently like this:

```
app.get('/songinfo', function(req, res) {
  request.get('http://songinfo.com/songs', function(err, res, data) {
    res.render('songinfo.ejs', data);
  });
});
```

You can change it to the following:

```
function getSongInfo(callback) {
  request.get('http://songinfo.com/songs', function(err, res, data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}

app.get('/songinfo', function(req, res) {
  getSongInfo(function(data) {
    res.render('songinfo.ejs', data);
  });
});

app.get('/raw-songinfo', function(req, res) {
  getSongInfo(function(data) {
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

What I've done here is pull out the `getSongInfo` logic to keep our app [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and added a second route that also uses that function, and rather than sending back the data in an ejs file, sends it back in json. Now, in your ejs file, you can add the logic for calling this route:

```
<button onclick='reloadData()'> Reload me! </button>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  function reloadData() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
          // Update the data in your app somehow...
          // example:
          var responseData = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          document.getElementById('songs-count').innerHTML = responseData.length;
        } else {
          alert('something went wrong!');
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I was planning out my code so I haven't had the opportunity to try this yet. I'm still trying to fix the scraper which seems to not want to grab the album name. I will post another comment when I do try this method though.